# Is mate choice in non-human primates MHC-dependent?

Tags: genetics, sexual-selection, immunity

Whether the major histocompatibility complex (MHC) affects or not mate choice in humans seems [mired in controversy](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3820490/) at the moment. Without implying that looking at non-human primates would solve this controversy, I'm still curious if some sort of scientific consensus could be reached in non-human primates regarding MHC and mate selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** It's messy for non-human primates too. [Winternitz et al. (2017)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27859823) ("Patterns of MHC‐dependent mate selection in humans and nonhuman primates: a meta‐analysis", *Molecular Ecology* 26(2)) review studies of MHC-based mate choice in human and non-human primates. Some of the take-home messages, mostly from the abstract:

> [abstract] the overall effect sizes of primate MHC-based mating preferences
>   are relatively weak ... calling for careful sampling design in future studies.

There is a

> "systematic trend" for primates preferring MHC diversity (p. 679)

(I think this means "not significant" ...)

> (p. 680) Nonhuman primates tend to consistently prefer MHC-dissimilar mates (Fig. 4a), but our power to detect a significant average effect is limited by our small sample size (N=6) and by the addition of random effects to control for pseudoreplication.

For MHC-diversity preferences:

> Examined separately ...  nonhuman primates had a non-significant trend for mate choice for diversity (primates = 0.110 (-0.207 to 0.456), N=7, Fig. 1b)

Here are some of the key figures (these figures also include data for humans, omitted here). However, note that the overall estimates in this figure **do not account for the effects of study ID and phylogenetic relatedness** (see Figure 1 in the paper), which tend to make the confidence intervals wider/weaken the statistical significance.

- Figure 4a, preference for MHC-dissimilar mates [disassortativity] (overall CI is [-0.01, 0.18], consistent with the "almost significant" comment referenced above)

[image]

- Figure 4b, preference for MHC-similar mates [assortativity]:

[image]

For reference, the species included here are: *Rhinopithecus roxellana* (golden/Sichuan snub-nosed monkey); *Cheirogaleus medius* (fat-tailed dwarf lemur); *Papio ursinus* (Chacma/Cape baboon); *Microcebus murinus* (gray mouse lemur); *Mandrillus sphinx* (mandrill); *Macaca mulatta* (Rhesus macaque).